# Wordpression : Role change with JSON REST API and update_user_meta, how to avoid double serializing?

Tags: wordpress, postman

This is for a videogame app interacting with a Wordpress. I can register, login, get auth cookie, get info from user via JSON API & JSON API USER for Wordpress. Everything's working fine, but lately it stopped working for updating the user role.

I'm using the update_user_meta method.
The meta_key is "wp_capabilities" and the meta_value should be :

```
 a:1:{s:7:"student";b:1;}
```

(serialized for array["student"])

But when I send this data with POSTMAN, it appears like serialized again in the database and the role doesnt work. It looks like this in the database after using the method:

```
s:24:"a:1:{s:7:"student";b:1;}";
```

Any idea how I can insert the proper value instead ?

I know we should not use update_user_meta with serialized data, but then how do I send unserialized data via POST to the REST API ?

Thanks for your help